# VAR(p) Model with difflog data

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, trend, differencing

I'm doing a regression analysis with a VAR model in R. My data is price and position data in the commodity market, since i want to find out (Granger) causality between them. I took the difflog for both time series (`diff(log(y)*100`). Does this mean, that I neither have trend nor a constant in the VAR model and thus can automatically choose `none` as the type?

I would be really thankful for some help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**None:** I would not choose `none` automatically, though it could be a reasonable choice for time series $X_t$ that do not grow exponentially.

**Constant:** If $X_t$ grows exponentially, $\log(X_t)$ has a linear trend and $\Delta\log(X_t)$ has a constant. Many economic variables could be assumed to grow exponentially (increase *on average* by a percent or two every year) due to inflation (this applies to nominal commodity prices) and due to real economic growth (this may or may not apply to both nominal and real commodity prices). Therefore, including a constant for $\Delta\log(X_t)$ may be logical.

**Trend:** A linear trend in $\Delta\log(X_t)$ would correspond to growth in $X_t$ accelerating at a constant rate (le.g. a percent last year, two percent this year, three percent next year etc.). This is less plausible for commodity prices (nominal or real), so including a trend for $\Delta\log(X_t)$ might be a bad idea.